# Norm or vector is increasing function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, normed-spaces

Given $f:(-1; 1) \to \mathbb{R}^2$. $f$ has a derivative over $(-1; 1)$ and $f(0) = \vec{0}$, but $f'(0) \neq 0$ and derivative is continous in $t=0$.

Prove, that there is an $\alpha \in (0; 1)$ such that $||f(t)||$ is increasing function over $(0; \alpha).$

I tried to suppose that there is no such $\alpha$ and applied mean value theorem for vector-valued functions, but got nothing good.

Comment: Are you sure this is true? I don't think it's true for real valued functions. I think you have to assume that the derivative is continuous in $t=0$.

Comment: @LorenzoPompili, thx fixed

Comment: So, if you are talking about the euclidean norm, you could write its square as the scalar product between $f(t)$ and itself. Then derivate this scalar product, and try to establish that its derivative is positive in a right neighbourhood of $t=0$